# Retrieve k-nearest spheres within a limited range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, acceleration

I would like to know if I am missing any acceleration structure that is designed for retrieving k-nearest **spheres** within a range.

The context of my question is molecular visualization, specifically, I need to retrieve k-nearest spheres to a point to produce a function that will be used to guide **sphere tracing** step length.
To simplify, the search can be limited in range to the point being tested.

All I have seen in the articles handle k-nearest points to a point, but my case is different, since I want to work with spheres closest to a point. It seems possible to adapt the kd-trees, changing the test of points to spheres but I believe that it would affect the performance. So I wonder if there is a better structure or if I should use and adapt the kd-trees.

Currently, I am using an Hybrid Bounding Volume Hierarchy but I think that the search performance could be better with other structure, since I have a big overlap of bounding volumes due to the nature of the molecules.

*PS: I don't care much about the construction time. I want good search performance and decent memory occupation.*

Comment: You can turn a range query between points in a kd-tree into a query between point and sphere since the distance between a point and a sphere is the distance between the point and the closest point on the sphere plus the radius of the sphere. Perform each range query by adding the largest radius in your structure and testing each candidate subtracting the radius of the candidate from its distance. This is assuming you use an adaptive range query for your knn.

Comment: But the spheres have a radius, how do you know it when building the structure?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3-step approach:

1. Find the nearest neighbor using the center-points of the spheres.
2. For this nearest neighbor you substract its radius and add the maximum radius. Then you Perform a spherical range query with the new distance. This will return all center points of spheres who may be the closest to your original sphere.
3. Then you manually calculate the actual distance for each sphere using it's actual radius.

This should be reasonably efficient assuming that the radius of spheres is not massively bigger than their average distance.